# Trying to process partial POST of data in REST when some data is successful?

Tags: rest, api-design

I have a resource that accepts array of numbers. Each number is proceed interdependently, and computation fails are expected. How should I communicate to API client "some of your numbers couldn't be proceed, but rest was successfully forwarded"?

Comment: I think it depends on how you access the resource and the structure of the resource itself.  Can you include a bit more detail?  Such as which verb you are using, the structure of the resource, and the nature of the partial failure?

Comment: You shouldn't. REST is stateless, each request is independent of the last and the next. If you are updating a resource to a new state that update should not depend on a previous request. If that update fails because the server will not allow the resource to be put into the state the client has put it in then return a 403 explaining why the server has forbidden that new state.

Comment: @CormacMulhall This really should be an answer. It is much better than the currently accepted answer as that one condones breaking principles of REST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the most straightforward method is just returning a XML or JSON, with the numbers and status.

Per your description, I imagine a structure like this would suffice:

```
{
   requestDate: '2015-02-05 12:32'
   results: [{
       number: 1,
       status: 'forwarded',
   },
   {
       number: 2,
       status: 'forwarded',
   },
   {
       number: 3,
       status: 'fail',
   }]
}
```

I also think a HTTP Status of 200 is most indicated, as the client request was successfully processed. Also you can [read in the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) (emphasis mine):

> 10.2.1 200 OK
>
> ...
>
> POST an entity describing or containing the **result of the action**;

**Edit:** Researching a little more about the status codes, I think it may be better to use `207 Multi-Status`:

> The message body that follows is an XML message and can contain a number of separate response codes, depending on how many sub-requests were made.[4]

Comment: Yes, it was my first idea. But should I use 200 HTTP status code if some of "subrequests" have failed?

Comment: I just edited the answer

Comment: This smells of a fudged REST implementation.

Comment: If the server rejects the new state of the resource you should not return 200. If a 200 is returned this implies that the client and server now both have the resource in the exact same state. If that isn't true, because the server has rejected the new state (even if just a bit of it) then the server must return a 4xx error explaining to the client why it could not accept the new state.

Comment: I disagree about the 4xx, it is for client errors, per the description of the OP, is appear to be a problems with the server proccess. Maybe it would be more indicated to use a "207 Multi-Status"

Comment: Depends on what caused the error. If the client is trying to put resource into a state the server won't allow due to an expected rule on the servers side then that is a 4xx since the client is making mistake. But yes if the server is having unexpected error that is a 5xx. Planning to have an unexpected error though is bad design.

Comment: An error,  client or server, should not result in a 2xx though.